# How to prove Bead-Sort is correct?

Tags: algorithms, sorting

"Consider a set X of n positive integers to be sorted and assume the biggest number in X is m. Then, the frame should have at least m rods and n levels." (see linked article below for illustration)

Algorithm as expressed in the article: For all x ∈ X, drop x beads (one bead per rod) along the rods, starting from rod 1 to rod x. Finally, the beads, seen level by level, from level n to the first level, represent X in ascending order.

"The Algorithm Bead-Sort is correct. We prove the result by mathematical induction on the number of rows of beads. We claim (1) that the set of positive integers represented by the states of the frame before and after the beads are dropped is the same. Also we claim (2) that the number of beads on each row i, after dropping, is at most the number
of beads on row i - 1 (the row directly below it).

Consider a set of cardinality n = 1. Since there is no possibility for a bead to drop the above two claims hold. Now assume these two properties hold for an input set whose cardinality is k. Suppose a row k + 1 of m'< m beads is now dropped on top of these k rows. Since claim (2) holds there is an index j ≤ m' such that all m' - j beads in columns greater than j drop down (from row k + 1). If m' - j = 0, we are done. Otherwise, the values of row k + 1 and row k have been swapped, with any excess beads on row k ready to drop further. Thus, claim (1) holds, after a series of at most k swaps. Claim (2) also holds since we repeat these swaps until the force of gravity cannot pull down any more beads."

I'm having trouble understanding the relevance of some of the assumptions in this proof:

1. Why does it matter if row k + 1 has m' < m beads? It seems to me the proof works even if m' > m or m' = m.
2. "There is an index j ≤ m' such that all m' - j beads in column greater than j drop down (from row k + 1)." How does this follow from claim (2)?
3. It isn't clear to me why claim (2) holds at the end of the proof. What is the author trying to convey here?

Here's a link to the article containing the algorithm and proof: https://researchspace.auckland.ac.nz/bitstream/handle/2292/3679/171joshua.pdf

Here's a Wiki link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bead_sort

Comment: I would include some link as o what the bead sort is, never heard of it before

Comment: $m'\le m$ is important at least because the number of rods was set to "at least m"; eg more beads wouldn't fit. The equality... Might either be an error, or the result of the fact that we're talking about sets, and thus, we can't have a duplicate of $m$

Comment: Are you looking for an alternate/simpler proof? I'm finding the wording of the given proof confusing and I think it's needlessly complex

Comment: @Alex K Yes, I think an alternate proof would be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate proof, for an arbitrary list of bounded positive integers (repeats are allowed). (Negative numbers can be supported by shifting everything).

I've made it pretty detailed, with a lot of stuff explicitly stated.

The statement of the algorithm is the same, except we now process $x_i$, for $i=1 \dots n$.

**Definition 1:** Let the number of beads on rod $j$ be $r_j$. The act of adding $x$ beads causes $r_j \leftarrow r_j + |j\le x|$. (That's a function that's 1 when $j\le x$.) Let $r_j=0$ for $j>m$.

**Definition 2:** Let $L_k$ be the number of beads at level $k$. Since beads fall to the bottom, $L_k=|\{j: r_j \ge k\}|$ (the number of rods with at least $k$ beads).

**Claim 1:** $r_j = |\{i : x_i >= j\}|$. (The number of $x$'s that are greater or equal to $j$.) This is trivially shown by looking at the updates to $r_j$ as indicator functions: $$
r_j = \sum_{k=1}^n |j\le x_k| = \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbf 1_{\{i:x_i\le j\}}(k)=|\{i : x_i >= j\}|
$$

**Claim 2:** $r_j$ is decreasing; $r_{j+1}\le r_{j}$. This is a consequence of claim 1: $\{i : x_i >= j+1\}\subseteq \{i : x_i >= j\}$.

Hence, $r_j\ge y \Rightarrow \forall 1\le i \le j,\,r_i\ge y$.

**Claim 3:** $L_k=\max \{i : r_i \ge k\}$. (The highest index of a rod with at least $k$ beads). This is a result of claim 2 applied to the definition $L_k=|\{i: r_i \ge k\}|$.

**Claim 4:** If $r_{j+1}<k$ and $r_j \ge k$, $L_k=\max \{i : r_i \ge k\}=j$, as an immediate consequence of claims 2 and 3. In other words, $L_k=j$ for all $r_{j+1}<k\le r_j$.

**Claim 5:** Claim 4 defines the value for all $L_k$ with $1\le k\le n$. The intervals have no overlap or gaps between them. $r_1=n$, and $r_{m+1}=0$, so no $k$ fall outside what is covered by the intervals.

**Claim 6:** Let $b_y=|\{i: L_i = y\}|$. (Number of rows with $y$ beads.) Then $r_y-r_{y+1} = b_y$.

From claim 4, $L_k=y$ for all $r_{y+1}<k\le r_y$, which is $r_y-r_{y+1}$ values of $k$; due to claim 5, there are no other $k$ with $L_k=y$.

**Claim 7**: Let $c_y=|\{i: x_i = y\}|$ (repeats of a specific value $y$ in the input). Then $r_y-r_{y+1} = c_y$. From claim 1:$$
r_y-r_{y+1}= |\{i : x_i >= y\}| - |\{i : x_i >= y+1\}|=
|\{i : x_i = y\}|
$$

**Claim 8:** $L_k$ is decreasing; $L_k \ge L_{k+1}$. This is a consequence of the definition of $L_k$: $\{j : r_j \ge k+1\} \subseteq \{j : r_j \ge k\}$

Claims 6 and 7 show that the list $L_1\dots L_n$ has the same members as $x_1 \dots x_n$ ($b_y=c_y$). Claim 8 shows that the result is sorted.